# Query fast when run separately but slow when added inside a join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, select

In SQL Server, this query runs very fast, less than a second:

```
SELECT T1.id
FROM first AS T1
WHERE T1.id = 21
```

This query also runs very fast, less than a second, even though it has 53 million records but only has about six records for id 21:

```
SELECT TOP 1 T2.value
FROM second AS T2 WITH(INDEX(IX_second))
WHERE T2.id = 21 
  AND T2.b = 1 
  AND T2.c = 0 
  AND T2.d = 0 
  AND T2.e = 0
ORDER BY T2.id, T2.b, T2.c, T2.d, T2.e, T2.timestamp DESC
```

However, this query, where I replace the 21 in the inner `SELECT` with T1.id, is very, very slow, more than 80 seconds:

```
SELECT T1.id, T3.value
FROM first AS T1
JOIN second AS T3 ON T3.id IN (SELECT TOP 1 T2.id
                               FROM second AS T2 WITH(INDEX(IX_second))
                               WHERE T2.id = T1.id 
                                 AND T2.b = 1 
                                 AND T2.c = 0 
                                 AND T2.d = 0 
                                 AND T2.e = 0
                               ORDER BY T2.id, T2.b, T2.c, T2.d, T2.e, T2.timestamp DESC)
 WHERE T1.id = 21
```

Why would this query take so very long and how do I make it faster?

---

Edit:
Here is the plan, with some table and field names changed to protect the innocent :) brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJYBSfwws

Comment: I suggest you 1. Tag the actual RDMBS (SQL Server? Oracle?) 2. Inspect the query plan

Comment: I edited the question to include "MS SQL Server".  Thank you for your comment.  The query plan wants to go through the entire 53 million records for some reason.

Comment: I edited the tags and added it, Now I suggest you use CTRL-L to capture and compare query plans. Look for high percentage operators

Comment: Are you certain that last query works? The syntax looks incorrect.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yes it does work. Common to do this inside an IN() statement

Comment: Your ORDER BY is overkill. You're adding processing time when ordering columns that are static in your WHERE clause

Comment: Yes you're right it's valid. It's just so out of the ordinary it looked wierd. Likely there is a better way to write this. First thing I note is that you don't use any fields from T2, so it could possibly be changed to `exists`

Comment: Without query plans I won't try and guess why it takes long I just know it looks intensive. Gut feel is that you can use `RANK()` or `ROW_NUMBER()` to tag the record you want in one pass rather than joining twice. Second observation is that you may beneift from a filtered index, filtering on that `where` predicate

Comment: And there is no need for an ORDER BY in the IN() statement. That definitely slows things down. I wouldn't use INDEX() either. Let DB decide

Comment: @Fandango68 - I need the ORDER BY so it gives me the record with the latest timestamp, hence the "timestamp DESC" at the end of the ORDER BY.

Comment: Its curious you are forcing the index selection, what happens if you let SQL Server choose its own index?

Comment: @DaleK that's exactly right and what I said above

Comment: It did the same thing whether or not I added the INDEX selection.

Comment: then remove it. Excess code

Comment: Well as best practice I recommend you don't because that restricts the options SQL Server has - and at some point that may cost you performance.

Comment: 1 way you can speed this up is put the results of one of your queries into a temp table, then join the temp table onto your second query.

Comment: But you have a data planning issue anyway.. no matter how you code this. 3 million rows are EACH running your subquery per record as NF said below. That *IS* your answer. Again you're not explaining what the real problem is you're having and you've not shown us your execution plan

Comment: @DaleK correct. Consider WITH CTE()

Comment: Yeah ^^^ use Paste The Plan to show use your execution plan. Otherwise we can't really assist.

Comment: @Fandango68 **no** not with a CTE... that still has a single execution plan and doesn't normally speed things up - in fact it can slow things down. Whereas a temp table solution splits into 2 execution plans, which SQL Server can do better with.

Comment: If you post sample data (i.e. table ddl and insert statements) I could pose an alternative query that yields the same results and _may_ run faster.

Comment: This small example is a part of a much bigger query.  The "21" is just an example of a field that will have many different IDs.  I "AM" using one field from T2 but it is through T3.value, which is the name in the outer query.  If the inside query works fast, why can't it work with an outer query that supplies the needed data to the inner query?  I am certainly not an expert on SQL but to me it seems the "21" is being provided by the outer query so it should work just as fast.

Comment: Here is the plan, with some table and field names changed to protect the innocent :) https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJYBSfwws

Comment: Try the temp table suggestion... sometimes SQL Server gets confused with a big execution plan, but can sort it out if the first resultset is stored in a temp table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a case where `CROSS APPLY` can be used. This allows the `TOP 1` and `ORDER BY`, but would avoid a double reference to the `second` table.

Try:

```
SELECT T1.id, T3.value
FROM first AS T1
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 T2.*
    FROM second AS T2 --WITH(INDEX(IX_second))
    WHERE T2.id = T1.id 
    AND T2.b = 1 
    AND T2.c = 0 
    AND T2.d = 0 
    AND T2.e = 0
    ORDER BY T2.id, T2.b, T2.c, T2.d, T2.e, T2.timestamp DESC
) T3
WHERE T1.id = 21
```

If `IX_second` is an index on `second(id)`, it is likely that the SQL server query optimizer will select that index without the need for an index hint.

Just to check: Are you sure you mean `T2.id = T1.id` and not something like `T2.first_id = T1.id`?

One more note: Since `T2.id, T2.b, T2.c, T2.d, T2.e` will all be fixed in the `CROSS APPLY` results, you can likely drop them from the `ORDER BY` clause.

ADDENDUM: Based on the query from your posted execution plan, the above would be equivalent to:

```
SELECT *
FROM Event_Item AS ei
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 eisp1.*
    FROM Event_Item_Spread AS eisp1
        -- WITH(INDEX(IX_Event_Item_Spread__event_item__sportsbook__period__ingame__alt__timestamp_desc))
    WHERE eisp1.event_item_id = ei.id
      AND eisp1.sportsbook_id = 1
      AND eisp1.period = 0
      AND eisp1.in_game = 0
      AND eisp1.alt = 0
    ORDER BY eisp1.timestamp DESC
) AS eisp
WHERE ei.id = 39604314
```

Answer (score 0):

All depends on the way the DBMS is computing the data.
But in this case 53M is going to be processed (T1 X T3) Times.
And each time there is going to do order, reverse, query, and possibly some join with source table if the index was not build with values (b,c,d,e...).

I don't get the logic of your query. Why not use just one join...

```
SELECT T1.id, T3.value
  FROM first AS T1
  JOIN second AS T2 ON T1.id = T2.id 
 WHERE T1.id = 21 
  AND T2.b = 1 AND T2.c = 0 AND T2.d = 0 AND T2.e = 0
```

This looks to have se same result as the above.

Comment: I can't just use one JOIN because I only want the TOP 1 of the results ordered by "timestamp desc".  Eventually I may also want just the TOP 2.  But I appreciate your answer, it just doesn't give me what I need.

Comment: @user1828108 but the OP was about why it is so slow. NF answered that. Maybe please expand your OP to include what you're after exactly.

Comment: Fandango68 - The answer includes "if the index was not build (sic) with values (b,c,d,e...)" but the index does include those fields.  Also, I only need the TOP 1 so the query doesn't work for what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Using sub-queries inside an `IN()` statement is syntactically ok, but I don't recommend it, as they are a slow way of managing JOINs between tables.

As per others have suggested, use a *temporary table*. Even a CTE() in my view is at least a cleaner version of the code and much easier to understand. You also need to study your execution plan.

I've not tested this, but try something like:

```
    SELECT TOP 1 T2.id
    INTO #tblTEMP1
    FROM second AS T2 
    WHERE T2.b = 1 
      AND T2.c = 0 
      AND T2.d = 0 
      AND T2.e = 0
    ORDER BY T2.id, T2.timestamp DESC
..
..
    SELECT T1.id, T3.value
    FROM first AS T1
    INNER JOIN #tblTEMP1 AS t ON t.ID = t1.ID
    INNER JOIN second AS T3 ON T3.id = t.ID
    WHERE T1.id = 21
```

I bet this will be faster, but perhaps not as fast as you'd expect.

Again, you need to study your execution plan each case and determine the exact bottle-neck(s) and place `INDEXes` where necessary.